# Large array definition problem in emu8086

Tags: image, assembly, drawing, emu8086

I want to draw the 200x200 sized picture that I have extracted the pixel coordinates to the screen using emu8086.I transfer the coordinates to the array and print to the screen, but I cannot print the entire array.When I checked the status, I noticed that the entire array was not memorized.How can I fix the problem or is there an alternative method? This is a required structure for my project.

My ASM code

```
 .stack 512
 .MODEL small 
DTSEG    SEGMENT
DATA_IN  DB 0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,025h,026h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,036h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,024h,025h,026h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,036h,037h,038h,06h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,023h,024h,025h,026h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,036h,037h,038h,039h,05h,06h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,016h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,022h,023h,024h,025h,026h,027h,028h,029h,032h,033h,034h,035h,036h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,04h,05h,06h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,021h,022h,023h,024h,025h,026h,027h,034h,035h,036h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h,08h,09h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,024h,025h,026h,036h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h,08h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,024h,025h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,024h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,01Fh,020h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,03Fh,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03Eh,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,03Dh,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h,08h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,03Ch,04h,05h,06h,07h,08h,09h,036h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,04h,05h,06h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,035h,036h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,03Bh,05h,06h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,034h,035h,036h,037h,038h,039h,03Ah,06h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,033h,034h,035h,036h,037h,038h,039h,07h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,032h,033h,034h,035h,036h,037h,038h,08h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,036h,037h,09h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,036h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,0Ah,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,035h,0Bh,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,034h,0Ch,0Dh,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,032h,033h,0Eh,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h,0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,015h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,015h,016h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,011h,012h,013h,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,012h,013h,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,019h,026h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,02Dh,013h,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,025h,026h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,02Ch,014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,024h,025h,026h,027h,028h,029h,02Ah,02Bh,016h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,023h,024h,025h,026h,027h,028h,029h,017h,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,022h,023h,024h,025h,026h,027h,028h,018h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,024h,025h,026h,027h,019h,1Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,024h,025h,026h,01Ah,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,024h,025h,01Bh,01Ch,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,023h,024h,01Dh,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h,022h,01Eh,01Fh,020h,021h

DATA_OUT  DB 03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,05h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,07h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,08h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,09h,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Bh,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Ch,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Dh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,010h,011h,011h,011h,011h,011h,011h,011h,011h,011h,011h,012h,012h,012h,012h,012h,012h,012h,012h,012h,012h,013h,013h,013h,013h,013h,013h,013h,013h,013h,013h,014h,014h,014h,014h,014h,014h,014h,014h,015h,015h,015h,015h,015h,015h,015h,015h,016h,016h,016h,016h,016h,016h,016h,016h,017h,017h,017h,017h,017h,017h,017h,017h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,019h,019h,019h,019h,019h,019h,019h,019h,019h,019h,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,1Ah,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Bh,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Ch,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Dh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Eh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,01Fh,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,020h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,021h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,022h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,023h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,024h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,025h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,026h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,027h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,028h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,029h,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Ah,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Bh,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Ch,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Dh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,02Fh,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,030h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,031h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,032h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,033h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,034h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,035h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,037h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,038h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,039h,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Ah,03Bh,03Bh,03Bh,03Bh,03Bh,03Bh,03Ch,03Ch,03Ch,03Ch

DTSEG ENDS       
        .CODE
screen macro 
    mov ah,00
    mov al,13h
    int 10h
endm

clear_screen macro  
    mov ax,600h 
    mov bh,07h  
    mov cx,0    
    mov bx,184fh 
    int 10h
endm
MAIN    PROC FAR  
        ASSUME DS:DTSEG
        MOV AX,DTSEG
        MOV DS,AX
        MOV AX,0xA000 
        MOV ES,AX
        MOV BX,OFFSET DATA_IN  
        MOV SI,OFFSET DATA_OUT 
        PUSH BX
        screen 
        POP BX 
        MOV CX,906 
   DNG:
        PUSH CX 
        XOR CX,CX
        mov cx,[BX]    
        XOR CH,CH 
        xor dx,dx
        mov dx,[SI] 
        xor dh,dh 
        PUSH BX
        xor bx,bx
        mov bh,0h ;sayfa sayisi
        POP BX
        mov ah,0ch 
        mov al,06
        int 10h
        INC SI
        INC BX  
        POP CX
        LOOP DNG 
        
        INT 21H
MAIN    ENDP
        END MAIN
; add your code here

ret
```

I tried it for a 64x64 image in the array here and the result is the same. waiting for your help

Comment: A data line with a `db` statement containing hundreds of elements is more unreadable than it has to be. Perhaps you could use multiple `db` statements, eg with 8 elements per line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing `MOV CX,906`, I'm guessing that, that is all that you could stuff in a single `db` line. Like @ecm told you in her comment, you should write the data on multiple `db` lines and preferably have the numbers aligned (for your own viewing pleasure):

```
X db  0Eh, 0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h,014h,02Bh
  db 02Ch,02Dh,02Eh,02Fh,030h,031h, 0Ah, 0Bh 
  db  0Ch, 0Dh, 0Eh, 0Fh,010h,011h,012h,013h
  db 014h,015h,016h,017h,018h,027h,028h,029h
  db ...

Y db 03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h
  db 03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,03h,04h,04h
  db 04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h
  db 04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h,04h
  db ...
```

Because your *DATA_IN* and *DATA_OUT* arrays are actually X and Y coordinates, why don't you name them more aptly *X* and *Y*?

---

The code has some more problems:

- In the *clear_screen* macro, the `mov bx,184fh` instruction is wrong in two ways. The LowerRightCorner must go in `DX` and for the 320x200 256-color screen (13h), the number of columns is 40, therefore 4Fh is not the correct value. Use `mov dx, 1827h`.
- Because you wrote `mov bh,0h ;sayfa sayisi` followed by `POP BX`, you will not have setup the DisplayPage in BH.
- The `INT 21H` instruction down below is missing its function number in AH. Probably you meant `mov ax, 4C00h` `int 21h`.

---

Quick fix so you can see what more improvements were possible!

```
        ...
        MOV  AX, DTSEG
        MOV  DS, AX
        screen
        MOV  si, OFFSET X  
        MOV  di, OFFSET Y 
        mov  bh, 0          ;sayfa sayisi
        MOV  CX, 906 
   DNG:
        PUSH CX 
        XOR  CX, CX
        mov  cl, [si]    
        xor  dx, dx
        mov  dl, [di]
        mov  ah, 0Ch 
        mov  al, 6         ; Brown
        int  10h
        INC  si
        INC  di 
        POP  CX
        LOOP DNG 
        
        mov  ax, 4C00h
        INT  21h
        ...
```